# Android MediaSession: How to choose the icons shown on lock screen?

Tags: android, audio, lockscreen, mediasession

I have an app that plays media via `MediaSessionCompat`.

I create a notification for the Notification Drawer using `NotificationCompat` and post it using `NotificationManagerCompat.notify`, and it looks great. (See screenshot.)

My problem is with the **lock screen**. It only shows Play, Previous Track, and Next Track icons. **I'm missing the controls to jump back and forward within the currently playing track.** (See screenshot.)

I'm using `MediaSession.setPlaybackState` to specify the actions that are available, and I am including all the appropriate ones from `PlaybackStateCompat` for rewind, fast forward, skip to previous, and skip to next.

Is the lock screen configured differently than the notification? Or do developers simply have less control over the controls provided here?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm adding a little more information here in the hopes it might help someone. I installed Pandora on this same phone just to see what they were doing, and sure enough, they offer much richer options via the Notification Drawer than via the lock screen. (The lock screen only shows a grayed out skip back button, a play button, and a skip forward button, whereas the Notification Drawer shows thumbs up, thumbs down, replay, play, and skip forward.) So it looks like the OS just decides on its own what to show on the lock screen.